Car around the track
I have wrote the code to achieve the AI to learn how to do a lap on its own. For that, I have used Pygame and NEAT.
When training the AI, the program can only take 4 decisions:

Forward
Right
Left
Nothing (moves it a bit forward, otherwise I got stuck with some genomes not moving at all)

The data fed to the AI is the distance between the car and the edge of the track in 5 points, forward, at +45 and -45 deg and +90 and -90 deg. See picture: 
Each green horizontal line at the track is the "checkpoints" or reward for the AI
Problem is, when I run the simulation, I some genomes are not reproducing but the best ones they keep repeating the same outputs over and over again indefinitely, and seems the AI is not learning at all just reproducing the over and over the best performance.
If population size is, lets say 20 cars, i end up only with the best car doing over and over the same route, instead of having the best car reproducing 20 times overwriting the "non good" ones.
Question:

How can I set the AI to get the best car and reproduce it but do not do the same route, but improvise a bit from it?

The NEAT file:
[NEAT]
fitness_criterion     = max
fitness_threshold     = 10000
pop_size              = 20
reset_on_extinction   = False

[DefaultGenome]
aggregation_default     = sum
aggregation_mutate_rate = 0.02
aggregation_options     = sum

# node activation options
activation_default      = relu
activation_mutate_rate  = 0.1
activation_options      = relu

# node bias options
bias_init_mean          = 0.0
bias_init_stdev         = 1.0
bias_max_value          = 30.0
bias_min_value          = -30.0
bias_mutate_power       = 0.6
bias_mutate_rate        = 1
bias_replace_rate       = 0.3

# genome compatibility options
compatibility_disjoint_coefficient = 1.0
compatibility_weight_coefficient   = 0.5

# connection add/remove rates
conn_add_prob           = 0.5
conn_delete_prob        = 0.8

# connection enable options
enabled_default         = True
enabled_mutate_rate     = 0.01

feed_forward            = True
initial_connection      = full_nodirect

# node add/remove rates
node_add_prob           = 0.2
node_delete_prob        = 0.5

# network parameters
num_hidden              = 10
num_inputs              = 3
num_outputs             = 4

# node response options
response_init_mean      = 1.0
response_init_stdev     = 0.0
response_max_value      = 30.0
response_min_value      = -30.0
response_mutate_power   = 0.01
response_mutate_rate    = 0.01
response_replace_rate   = 0.01

# connection weight options
weight_init_mean        = 0.0
weight_init_stdev       = 1.0
weight_max_value        = 30
weight_min_value        = -30
weight_mutate_power     = 0.5
weight_mutate_rate      = 0.8
weight_replace_rate     = 0.1

[DefaultSpeciesSet]
compatibility_threshold = 3.0

[DefaultStagnation]
species_fitness_func = max
max_stagnation       = 2
species_elitism      = 1

[DefaultReproduction]
elitism            = 3
survival_threshold = 0.2

Question:

How can I set the AI to get the best car and reproduce it but do not do the same route, but improvise a bit from it?


Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with this particular program (and therefore am unlikely to answer), but do you by chance have a public git you could share with the code for people to run? It might be helpful for them to be able to run the code themselves in order to reproduce and better understand what you're seeing.
